# Replace value in pandas

Tags: python, regex, replace

I have a column of dates and time stamps (eg: 01/15/1880 01:25:45 AM). I want to iterate through all rows and replace each value with just the year. This is all I have so far, using a regex to pull out the year:

```
for i in df['year']:
   i=str(i)
   yr=re.findall('\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2}\/(\d{4})', i)
```

Comment: There is only one signature of 4 digits. If the field is already correctly formatted, just a simple `.*(\d{4}).*` is all  you need.

Comment: Try `df['just_year'] = df['year'].str.findall(r'\d{1,2}/\d{1,2}/(\d{4})').apply(','.join)`

Answer (score 0):

That's not how pandas is supposed to be used. The point of having pandas (well, one of the points) is to avoid loops and apply vectorized operations instead. Convert you string-like fields to proper `DateTime`'s and extract the year field:

```
df['year_only'] = pd.to_datetime(df['year']).dt.year
```

If any of your years is less than 1970 (the beginning of Unix epoch), you can indeed use regular expressions (but still no loops):

```
df['year_only'] = df['year'].apply(lambda x: re.findall(r'/(\d{4})',x)[0])
```

Comment: Thanks, I get the 'out of bounds nanosecond timestamp' error, but I'm on the right track now.

Comment: Do you have years earlier than 1970? (That would explain it.) See updated answer.

Comment: Yes, these go back to the nineteenth century... I will play with this. Great.